# How to avoid N+1 problem using eager fetching

Tags: hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple data model. `Student` has a `ManyToOne` relation ship with a `Class`. `Class` has a `OneToMany` relation ship with `Teacher` (for example), the same teacher does not teach more than on class.

My entity is defined as

```java
@Entity("student")
class Student{
     
   @Id
   private int id;

   @Column
   private String name;
}

@Entity("class")
class Class{
     
   @Id
   private int id;

   @Column
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "STUDENT_CLASS",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="CLASS_ID")}
   )
   private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(
      name="CLASS_TEACHER",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="CLASS_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID")}
   )
   private Set<Teacher> targets = new HashSet<Teacher>();
}
```

I'm using spring boot: spring data jpa 2, with Hibernate as JPA implementation.

Obviously the above mapping is resulting in N+1 calls, more the associations more the calls are.

I could construct my own SQL with all the joins and map it, so that the query gets executed only once, and I can build the necessary object graph in the memory.

And also I need to do eager fetching, as I would be passing the object graph around and Hibernate session may be out of scope.

How can I still avoid the N+1 issue, with eager fetching and not getting into writing my own SQL joins.

Comment: Actually, mapping does not generate any query. Please show what exactly query do you execute? What spring data jpa repository methods do you use?

Comment: Look also at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-fetching-associations). `EAGER` fetching is almost always a bad choice. The `EAGER` fetching strategy cannot be overwritten on a per query basis, so the association is always going to be retrieved even if you don’t need it. Moreover, if you forget to `JOIN FETCH` an `EAGER` association in a JPQL query, Hibernate will initialize it with a secondary statement, *which in turn can lead to N+1 query issues.*

Answer (score 0):

JPA has the concept of join fetching which you can use. You can find more information about this in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching